# Is there a way to Select the Entity that Activates the Command Block / Sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is a very important Question to me, as it relates to my Server/Realm as I use completely command blocks for everything, and due to the point that the closest thing to detecting the activator is using @p, I guess you could see where that would go wrong with a lot of players.

So if anyone can, is there a method of using /execute or /testfor to detect this?
I'm trying to teleport specific players who click a button by the way. Also I have a sign that when clicked also teleports the players, is there a method of doing this for command signs aswell?

Comment: Pressure plates and x y z dx dy dz

Comment: Oh wait, you also listed signs in the title. Yes, it actually works with those.

Comment: @FabianRöling The issue is that im using signs and buttons, not prssure plates, and I dont like settin up scoreboards

Comment: Triggers are the one way to do it, they are made for that. If you don't like setting up scoreboards, then you can't do what you want. May I ask why you don't like them? Do you not understand how they work for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a player clicks on a sign with a command, it's automatically executed as that player, so you can use a [trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/trigger) command to let the player set a score for themselves by clicking the sign. Then you just do things based on that score.

Answer (score 0):

if on anything other than Java, do
    testfor [x=<#>,y=<#>,z=<#>,dx=<#>,dy=<#>,dz=<#>]

(this pic is only an example the shaded area is the range area, the d stands for distance from command block)

[image: add picture description]